# Extracting and storing data to ostream

Tags: c++, fstream

Is it possible to store data to an `ostream` like this

```
void write(std::ostream& os){
  int x,y = 0; bool b = true;
  os<<x<<" "<<y<<" "<<b<<std::endl;
}
```

and then extract data from it like this

```
void read(std::istream& is){
  unsigned int x,y,b;
  is>>x>>y>>b; // I want to take x,y,b and make store them in a object but it is not important I want to know if I can extract information from istream like this and use x,y,b
}
```

I tried to make a simple program to just try that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::fstream file(argv[1]);
  if (!file.is_open()){
    std::cerr<<"erreur"<<std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  bool v = false;
  size_t x = 1;
  size_t y = 2;
  for(size_t i=0;i<4;i++) {
    file<<v<<" "<<x<<" "<<y<<std::endl;
  }
  for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    bool b; size_t a; size_t c;
    file>>b>>a>>c;
    std::cout<<b<<a<<c<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but my output is this:

```
026422044
026422044
026422044
026422044
```

Comment: Have you tried? What is the problem?

Comment: @Egv I am getting a bunch of random numbers when I print them like std::cout<<x<<y<<b; I am editing my question to be more specific.

Comment: `int x,y = 0;` only initialize `y`. The variable `x` remains uninitialized with an indeterminate values. Using `x` will lead to *undefined behavior*. To initialize both variables you must initialized both explicitly, as in `int x = 0, y = 0;`. This is one reason it's recommended to only define one variable per statement, as mistakes like that won't happen then.

Comment: As for the problem with the file, the simple solution is to close the file once you've written to it, then reopen it for the reading.

Comment: Why don't you check stream state after IO operations? Are you sure that `file>>b>>a>>c;` actually reads anything?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude like this?:   file.close();
  std::ofstream file1(argv[1]);
  if (!file1.is_open()){
    std::cerr<<"erreur"<<std::endl;
    return 1;
  } because that gave me a lots of erreurs

Comment: You can use `seekg(0)` before reading. Also note that by default `std::fstream` does **not** create new files. You'll get an error if the file doesn't already exists.

Comment: The `o` in `ofstream` is for *output*. You can't read from an output stream. And that's not really what I meant anyway. After writing: `file.close();` and before reading `file.open(argv[1]);`

Comment: @Evg thank you after closing and reopening the file it worked I think it was your point the reading part was not reading anything because there was nothing to read until I close and reopen the file

Comment: When you reopen the file you effectively reset the position indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After closing and reopening the file my problem fixed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::ofstream file(argv[1]);
  if (!file.is_open()){
    std::cerr<<"erreur"<<std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  bool v = false;
  size_t x = 1;
  size_t y = 2;
  for(size_t i=0;i<4;i++) {
    file<<v<<" "<<x<<" "<<y<<std::endl;
  }
  file.close();
  std::ifstream file1(argv[1]);
  if (!file1.is_open()){
    std::cerr<<"erreur"<<std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  for (size_t j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    size_t b; size_t a; size_t c;
    file1>>b>>a>>c;
    std::cout<<b<<a<<c<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `file1 >> b >> a >> c` can fail and then `a`, `b`, `c` output is meaningless. You should check the stream state after IO operations.

Comment: Do I have to something like if(!file1.eof()) or (file1.good()) before file1 >> b >> a >> c to be sure?

Comment: Not before, but after: `if (file1 >> b >> a >> c) /* use values */`. The same for writing.